# Proving two topological spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, homotopy-theory

> Prove the surface $\mathbb{S}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is homeomorphic to $\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:u^2+v^2\le 1\}$ where $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$. You may assume $\mathbb{S}^2$ is equipped with the subspace topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So my understanding is that we are done if we can find a homeomorphism from one to the other (i.e. a function which is bijective and bicontinuous). However the problem I'm having with this is firstly that I cannot think of such a function. Secondly, what is the point of the specific topologies here? I cannot seem to figure out why the specific topology assigned should make a difference.

Comment: A homeomorphism is a map that is continuous between topological spaces i.e. the inverse image of open should be open in order to think about open sets your need to have a topology.

Comment: Think about $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{z^2} + \frac{y^2}{z^2} = \frac{1}{z^2}-1$ you need to deal with the case of $z$ equal zero.

Comment: those are not homemorphic, are you sure of the statement?

Comment: This is not true, so you'll have trouble proving it.

Comment: It is not true because $S^2\setminus\{p\}$ is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) for every $p\in S^2,$ whereas $\bar D_1\setminus\{q\}$ is not, for many $q$'s in $\bar D_1.$ Are you confusing with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997089)?

Comment: @IrbidMath i've edited the question; missed out a key part of the definition

Comment: @alidixon222 Your edit was rejected because it did not respect what the OP meant.